# I can not create user in mongodb, must be function is wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

hi I wanna see on the screen User all information  but I cannot add user in mongodb . User's location information in Locations Schema.But I dont know how to get location information(i.e city,town...)  to input UserSchema.This is my codes:

User Schema :

```
var userSchema = Mongoose.Schema({ 

        name:{type: String,require:true},
        surname: {type: String,require:true},
        tel: {type: String,require:true},
        age: {type: String,require:true},
        mevki_id: {type: String,require:true},
        location_id: { type: [Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'locations' }



});

Create User Function :
this.createUser = function (req, res, next) {
       var lok=new Location({il:req.params.il,ilce:req.params.ilce});
               lok.save(function(err){
   var user=new User({name:req.params.name,surname:req.params.surname,tel:req.params.tel,age:req.params.age,mevki_id:req.params.mevki_id,location_id:user});
         user.save(function(err){

          user.location_id=lok;
                 });
 return res.send({})
                 });    
                 }
```

Thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//define this as your schema in your file

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    surname: {type: String, required: true},
    tel: {type: Number, required: true},
    age: {type: Number, required: true},
    mevki_id: {type: String, required: true},
    location_id:{type:String,required:true}
});
var CollectionModel_user = conn.model('users', userSchema)

return function (req, res, next) {
        req.Collection_user = CollectionModel_user;
        next();
    }

   // create a route which can create a route in your
   // app.js or main.js file that will create a new
   // collection in your mongo.

    router.all('/user/create', function (req, res) {
    var create = req.Collection_user;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var surname = req.body.surname;
    var tel = req.body.tel;
    var age = req.body.age;
    var mevki_id = req.body.mevki_id;
    var location_id = req.body.location_id;
    var record = new create({
        name: name,
        surname: surname,
        tel: tel,
        age: age,
        mevki_id: mevki_id,
        location_id: location_id
    });
    if (name.length > 0) {
        record.save(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({status: 0, message: err})
            } else {
                res.json({status: 1, message: " success"});
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.json({status: 0, msg: "Invalid Fields"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfornutely it didnt work I guess create function is wrong beause it have to create both location schema and  userschema at the same time.And then I have to get location id in location schema , put into user schema and when ı cal get user , User have location information anymore but I dont know how to do this :(